# Receiving funds in multisig - is it enough to confirm the receive address on every signing device?

Tags: address, multi-signature, wallet-security, receiving, xpub

If I confirm the receive address displayed in my software wallet matches on EVERY signing device in my multisig setup, can I be confident that any funds sent to that address belong to an address I control? (assuming I haven't lost the seed phrases/xpubs)

Or are there other critical steps I should consider before sending a large transaction to one of my addresses?